# Ruby refactoring, can't seem to get the syntax right

Tags: ruby

I'm pretty new at Ruby and I've been asked to help out on a program. For some reason for the life of me I can't get my syntax right. If the agent relationship is none?, I want to unshift both the 'series_system_agent_record_creation_by_agent_relationship' and 'series_system_agent_record_ownership_relationship'. I'm using the && in my code but it's not doing what I need it to do so any help would be much appreciated!

```rb
if whitelisted['agent_relationships'].none? {|r| r['jsonmodel_type'] == 'series_system_agent_record_creation_by_agent_relationship'}
  whitelisted['agent_relationships'].unshift({
    'jsonmodel_type' => 'series_system_agent_record_creation_by_agent_relationship',
    'relationship_target_record_type' => 'agent_corporate_entity',
    'ref' => json.creating_agency[0]['ref'],
    'relator' => 'created_by',
    'start_date' => json.creating_agency[0]['start_date'],
  })
end

if whitelisted['agent_relationships'].none? {|r| r['jsonmodel_type'] == 'series_system_agent_record_ownership_relationship'}
  whitelisted['agent_relationships'].unshift({
    'jsonmodel_type' => 'series_system_agent_record_ownership_relationship',
    'relationship_target_record_type' => 'agent_corporate_entity',
    'ref' => json.responsible_agency['ref'],
    'relator' => 'is_controlled_by',
    'start_date' => json.responsible_agency['start_date'],
  })
end

    whitelisted['responsible_agency'] = json.responsible_agency
    whitelisted['creating_agency'] = json.creating_agency
```

Sorry just a quick edit. To make sense of this the .none? is because I'm using an outdated version of Ruby for an older program. Not something I can change because it isn't my choice. To add I want to **refactor** this code. I know it already works. I've already tried a few ways and my head can't wrap my head around how to do it. Eg. I tried

```
if whitelisted['agent_relationships'].none? {|r| r['jsonmodel_type'] == 'series_system_agent_record_creation_by_agent_relationship' && 'series_system_agent_record_creation_by_agent_relationship'}
  whitelisted['agent_relationships'].unshift({
    'jsonmodel_type' => 'series_system_agent_record_creation_by_agent_relationship',
    'relationship_target_record_type' => 'agent_corporate_entity',
    'ref' => json.creating_agency[0]['ref'],
    'relator' => 'created_by',
    'start_date' => json.creating_agency[0]['start_date'],
  } && {
        'jsonmodel_type' => 'series_system_agent_record_creation_by_agent_relationship',
        'relationship_target_record_type' => 'agent_corporate_entity',
        'ref' => json.creating_agency[0]['ref'],
        'relator' => 'created_by',
        'start_date' => json.creating_agency[0]['start_date'],
      }
  )
end

whitelisted['responsible_agency'] = json.responsible_agency
whitelisted['creating_agency'] = json.creating_agency
```

Hello again! I've now also tried another method as well and I am not running into any errors however something seems to be wrong as this program is whitelisting relationships that can be passed to a react front end. Now none of the relationships are appearing on the react front end using the code below and although I am not running into any errors, it is still not working.

```
    if whitelisted['agent_relationships'].none? {|r| r['jsonmodel_type'] == 'series_system_agent_record_ownership_relationship' && 'series_system_agent_record_creation_by_agent_relationship'}
      [{
        'jsonmodel_type' => 'series_system_agent_record_ownership_relationship',
        'relationship_target_record_type' => 'agent_corporate_entity',
        'ref' => json.responsible_agency['ref'],
        'relator' => 'is_controlled_by',
        'start_date' => json.responsible_agency['start_date'],
      },{
        'jsonmodel_type' => 'series_system_agent_record_creation_by_agent_relationship',
        'relationship_target_record_type' => 'agent_corporate_entity',
        'ref' => json.creating_agency[0]['ref'],
        'relator' => 'created_by',
        'start_date' => json.creating_agency[0]['start_date'],
      },].each { |hsh| ['agent_relationships'].unshift(hsh) }
    end

whitelisted['responsible_agency'] = json.responsible_agency
whitelisted['creating_agency'] = json.creating_agency
```

Comment: "it's not doing what I need it to do" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: You write that you "can't seem to get the syntax right",  but the syntax *does* look right, and Ruby agrees with me: if I psrse your code with the `ruby -c` syntax checker, it says "Syntax OK". Your question is also somewhat confusing: are you using [tag:ruby-on-rails-5] or are you using [tag:sinatra], or both? And note that the syntax is fixed by the language specification and cannot be changed by libraries, so it doesn't actually matter.

Comment: Try to use `.empty?` instead of `.none?`

Comment: Hannah the .none? method has been deprecated since Rails 2.3 (https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/none%3F) , but if you're simply trying to check that a relationship has no records, you can still use none? to check if there are no records and you'll get 'true' back.  Like the other commenters - what you're trying to achieve isn't clear from the original post.

Comment: This is not a [mre] as there appears to be a lot of extraneous and unnecessary code here. I imagine that if you reduce it to an MRE with the absolute bare minimum amount of code necessary to reproduce it that you'll solve this on your own.

Comment: Hi sorry everyone! So it is working completely fine but I just wanted to refactor my code. Ruby isn't something I know inside out because I'm super new to it. When I did refactor my code to include both 'series_system_agent_record_creation_by_agent_relationship'' && 'series_system_agent_record_ownership_relationship' in the first line. Also the reason why I have to use .none? is because I'm trying to help fix a ruby program that is using ruby version that is outdated. And sorry for re-looking this isn't rails but just a simple ruby program. Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: `<hash>.unshift(<hash1> && <hash2>)` isn't doing what you want - it's just unshifting `true` because `&&` returns a boolean. Rather use `[<hash1>, <hash2>].each { |hsh| <hash>unshift(hsh) }`

Comment: Thank you @maxpleaner for the helpful response. I've edited the question above trying your method and see what you mean but my only issue is although I am not getting any errors, it is not appearing at all on the react front end for this because this maps to be indexed from the react front end. I don't know if it's a syntax thing on my end from the way I've written it.

Comment: In the original code, bith `if` conditions look very similar (just the value to compare to in the block differs a bit), so on refactoring, I would put this into a seaparate method, where i.e. `'series_system_agent_record_ownership_relationship'` is passed as parameter.

Comment: When you're trying to refactor a big chunk of code like this, my strong advice is to start by writing a thorough set of tests. When you have a set of tests that validates every expected behaviour, only then can you safely refactor. If this is your own code, then the best approach would have been to write the tests right from the start. For complex logic, it's really the best way. I realize that this can seem like unproductive overhead to a newcomer, but you will really come to value the assurance that the code is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from initial code you want to add `series_system_agent_record_creation_by_agent_relationship` default only if it's missing in whitelist. Same with `series_system_agent_record_ownership_relationship` - add only when it's missing.

However your refactoring tries to add both at a time.

Refactoring is usually a process when you refactor little bit and then it gives you idea what else can be refactored.

I would start with replacing long names.
One of the initial versions could be.

```
def whatever_the_name
  # ...
  unless has_agent_relationship_of_type?(whitelisted, 'series_system_agent_record_creation_by_agent_relationship')
    creating_agency = json.creating_agency[0]
    default_agent_relationship = {
        'jsonmodel_type' => 'series_system_agent_record_creation_by_agent_relationship',
        'relationship_target_record_type' => 'agent_corporate_entity',
        'ref' => creating_agency['ref'],
        'relator' => 'created_by',
        'start_date' => creating_agency['start_date'],
    }

    whitelisted['agent_relationships'].unshift(default_agent_relationship)
  end

  unless has_agent_relationship_of_type?(whitelisted, 'series_system_agent_record_ownership_relationship')
    responsible_agency = json.responsible_agency
    default_agent_relationship = {
        'jsonmodel_type' => 'series_system_agent_record_ownership_relationship',
        'relationship_target_record_type' => 'agent_corporate_entity',
        'ref' => responsible_agency['ref'],
        'relator' => 'is_controlled_by',
        'start_date' => responsible_agency['start_date'],
    }

    whitelisted['agent_relationships'].unshift(default_agent_relationship)
  end

  # ...
end


def has_agent_relationship_of_type?(whitelisted, type)
  whitelisted['agent_relationships'].any? {|r| r['jsonmodel_type'] == type }
end
```

Of course, this shouldn't be considered the final refactored code. It all depends how far you want to get. But hopefully it helps.

Comment: Hi thank you for the help! I totally get what you're saying with the long names but unfortunately this is just a small snippet of a huge program so I'm not allowed to change the names. On top of that it's been pulled to a react front end and the json parts needs to be formatted perfectly for it to come through. My questions is with the last method would need to be applied on the creating_agency whitelisted and responsible_agency? Sorry I'm just getting more and more confused as I go along to be honest.

Comment: Unfortunately without knowing what this app is doing it's hard to tell what you should do.
But from the initial snippet you've provided I didn't change the logic much, I just extracted some structures into its own names to be able to understand what is going on.

Comment: And from what I understand - if value does not exist you add some sort of default value to the front of whitelisted (does it matter, btw?)

Comment: _without knowing what this app is doing it's hard to tell what you should do_ This is exactly the reason the problem should be made generic, not specific, as a [mre].